# What could prevent ping answers?

Tags: networking, router, ping, switch

At my customer's place there is a wired network composed in this way:

- ADSL router (the config page is not accessible, the boss needs to call the provider to make changes)
- 32-port switch
- some cables go from the switch to the office
- here another switch provides connections for the laptops, printers, router, etc...
- two cables go from the switch to the production area
- for each one, there are 4-5 switches connected in chain, and each switch connects 3-4 PLCs
- my server is connected to the main switch directly

The office devices receive the IP address from the DHCP inside the subnet 192.168.0.0/16.
The production devices (PLCs) are set with static addresses inside the subnet 192.168.1.0/16.
My server (Linux) has a static address inside the subnet 192.168.0.0, but *outside* the DHCP range.

The last time I worked on the project, say before summer, from my server I can ping all the PLCs. Now, I can ping only few of them (with correct timings) and time by time the "available" ones change. The boss says no changes were made in the network. I can just guess some changes in the router configuration (i.e. firmware update).

A laptop (Windows) connected in another port of the main switch (so just on the side of my server) pings all the PLCs.

I'm not sure what other information I should provide, but my question is: **what could prevent my server from pinging the devices?** Not *all* devices, but only some of them with random criteria (apparently).

I've already tried to change the switch port.

The devices that are up and running that do not answer to the ping, return something like this:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.17
PING 192.168.1.17 (192.168.1.17) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Where `192.168.1.17` is the PLC and `192.168.0.100` is my server.

### UPDATE

Here a simple diagram of the network:

```
                                                  .0.15
      .0.100           ┌──────────┐             ┌──────────┐
     ┌────────┐        │  OFFICE  ├─────────┬──►│ LAPTOP1  │
     │ SERVER │◄─────┐ │  SWITCH  │         │   └──────────┘
     │        │      │ └──────────┘         │     .0.16
     └────────┘      │       ▲              │   ┌──────────┐
                     │       │              ├──►│ LAPTOP2  │
                     │       │              │   └──────────┘
     ┌────────┐    ┌─┴───────┴────────┐     │     .0.17
     │ ROUTER │    │                  │     │   ┌──────────┐
     │ MODEM  ├───►│   MAIN SWITCH    │     └──►│ PRINTER  │
     │ ADSL   │    │                  │         └──────────┘
     └────────┘    └──┬────────────┬──┘
--------------------- │ ---------- │ -----------------------
                      ▼            ▼
     ┌───────┐    ┌────────┐  ┌────────┐    ┌───────┐
.1.11│ PLC 1 │◄─┬─┤ SWITCH │  │ SWITCH ├─┬─►│ PLC 7 │.1.17
     ├───────┤  │ │   L1   │  │   R1   │ │  ├───────┤
     ├───────┤  │ └───┬────┘  └────┬───┘ │  ├───────┤
.1.12│ PLC 2 │◄─┘     │            │     └─►│ PLC 8 │.1.18
     └───────┘        │            │        └───────┘
                      ▼            ▼
     ┌───────┐    ┌────────┐  ┌────────┐    ┌───────┐
.1.13│ PLC 3 │◄─┬─┤ SWITCH │  │ SWITCH ├─┬─►│ PLC 9 │.1.19
     ├───────┤  │ │   L2   │  │   R2   │ │  ├───────┤
     ├───────┤  │ └───┬────┘  └────┬───┘ │  ├───────┤
.1.14│ PLC 4 │◄─┘     │            │     └─►│ PLC 10│.1.20
     └───────┘        │            │        └───────┘
                      ▼            ▼
     ┌───────┐    ┌────────┐  ┌────────┐    ┌───────┐
.1.15│ PLC 5 │◄─┬─┤ SWITCH │  │ SWITCH ├─┬─►│ PLC 11│.1.21
     ├───────┤  │ │   L3   │  │   R3   │ │  ├───────┤
     ├───────┤  │ └────────┘  └────────┘ │  ├───────┤
.1.16│ PLC 6 │◄─┘                        └─►│ PLC 12│.1.22
     └───────┘                              └───────┘
```

Comment: @spikey_richie sorry, read again the question. The Windows laptop pings all the devices, is my Ubuntu server that can't reach some of them (anymore).

Comment: Why do you seem to have multiple cables between switches? What kind of PLC network(s) are the PLCs forming? Do you have network loops?

Comment: What are the actual subnets? You say 192.168.1.0/16, but... a /16 goes all the way from .0.0 to .255.255 (not just 192.168.1.0-255 – that would be a /24). Is it one large subnet, or two subnets separated by a router, or two subnets sharing the same ethernet?

Comment: To the close vote: I explicity stated: "I'm not sure what other information I should provide". So if it needs more focus, please ask questions like the other users because - honestly - I don't know what's really matter here

Comment: @Spiff, there are a lot of switches placed in the building, but each one is connected to the other with one cable only. I'm not aware about network loops (it should be a "tree" topology) but I didn't cable the network by myself. The PLCs are just the "leaves" of the tree, each one connected to a switch. I'm going to add a simple diagram to the question

Comment: @user1686, /16 is needed because the server (192.168.0.100) needs to communicate with both 192.168.0.x devices and 192.168.1.x devices. The addresses are split in two "logical" subnets: 192.168.0.[1..254] for the offices devices and 192.168.1.[1..254] for the production devices (PLCs)

Comment: @user1686 sorry, I got your point. I'm not sure why it was /16. /23 would be enough indeed. Perhaps they wanted to leave open other subnets for future uses, I don't know.

Comment: @Mark: Well, it's not about "too large" but about whether the devices consider each other to be in the same subnet or not – sometimes such problems occur when devices disagree on the configured subnet mask, i.e. A thinks B is in the same subnet but B thinks otherwise. (Though I have to say, office PCs and PLC devices sharing the same subnet is frankly a bit scary. Do your office PCs specifically need layer2 reachability to the PLC devices? If not, they could perfectly well be on two *separate* subnets with a router in between.)

Comment: Are other devices (office PCs) able to ping the PLCs that become unreachable from the server? Are you able to connect a laptop to the main switch, or to one of the PLC switches (e.g. the same switch that the PLC itself is connected to)? Do the switches themselves have IP addresses -- do they remain pingable? does their status page show the PLC port "up"? are they running STP/RSTP or some kind of "loop protection" feature?

Comment: @user1686 unfortunately I cannot answer to all your questions now. But: a Windows laptop connected to the main switch (see question) pings all the PLCs. The Linux server *was* able to ping all the PLCs, until *something* happened (not in the server, not in the network). As far as I know, the switches haven't a IP address themselves and I don't think they have a "status pages". They are the common 5-port switches from TP-Link or D-Link.